# Node JS route not firing with multiple segments

Tags: node.js, express, routes

OK so I am not sure exactly why this is happening. I tried searching for this but I am not sure how to word it - something like "multiple url segments not firing route." ?

Either way here we go...

Using node.js and Express: I have a route in my app.js that looks like this:

```
app.get('/kosk/:id/:key', kosk.kosk);
```

If I then go to (http://my.nodeserv.com:8080/kosk/451/123456) I get a 404 not found from the server.

BUT if I do this:

```
app.get('/kosk/:id', kosk.kosk);
```

And then go here (http://my.nodeserv.com:8080/kosk/451) - all works fine, the route triggers and I get my param.

The code in the route is set up to handle the items coming in, but I don't understand why the route in this format is not triggered. Again, node answers back with a 404 not found for the multiple segment url. Any ideas? I am hoping I have just missed something simple and can't see around it. Thanks in advance for any help/ideas!

Answer (score 0):

According to your snippet it should work. You may want to verify that it's not something else by making sure the following works:

```
app.get('/foo/:bar/:baz', function(req, res) {
  res.json({
    bar: req.params.bar,
    baz: req.params.baz                                                                                      
  });
});
```

Sending a `GET` request to `http://localhost:3000/foo/123/456` should respond with:

```
{
  "bar": "123",
  "baz": "456"
}
```

I just did this by creating a new express project and defining the above route for sanity. It worked well for me so I think it might be some other part of your `app.js`/`server.js` file that's giving you this problem.

Comment: Thanks so much - Still getting used to Node so didn;t think to try that. That came back ok in my app and led me to the real issue - it was an issue with the return value of my function in the route being triggered.